# Hyperledger Fabric-ca connection on LDAP

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, openldap, ca, hyperledger-fabric-ca

We are implementing a Hyperledger Fabric solution. To do so, we set up a fabric-CA, using the minimal configuration (we are still trying to figure out how the things works) in a specific docker.

As we need to login our users, using a email/password couple, we set up a LDAP component. We choosed to use OpenLDAP, using osixia/openldap implementation in a different docker.

We set the parameters in the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml to connect Fabric CA to the LDAP. At the start of both dockers, the logs seems fine :

```
Successfully initialized LDAP client
```

When we carry on the Fabric-CA tutorial, we fail at the command :

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://cn=admin,dc=example:admin@localhost:7054
```

The result is :

```
Post https://localhost:7054/enroll: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "fabric-ca-server")
```

The LDAP is setup and functionning correctly, when sollicitated in CLI and via PHPLdapAdmin, an LDAP Browser, using the same credentials.

This is a bit of the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:

```
ldap:
  enabled: true
  url: ldap://cn=admin,dc=example:admin@localhost:389/dc=example
  userfilter: (uid=%s)
tls:
  certfiles: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/org1.tbp.com-cert.pem
  client:
     certfile: /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-client/msp/cacerts/localhost-7054.pem
     keyfile:
attribute:
  names: ['uid','member']
  converters:
    - name: hf.Revoker
      value: attr("uid") =~ "revoker*"
  maps:
    groups:
      - name:
      value:
```

Anyone could help ?
Thanks for reading,

Comment: The first step here would be to use the `--tls.certfiles` flag for the `fabric-ca-client`.  You'll want to set the value to the root cert(s) which issued the TLS certificate for the fabric-ca-server

Comment: If I understand your comment, I have to modify `fabric-ca-server start` to add the flag `--tls.cerfiles`, specifying the path to the TLS certs, **on my machine**. Right ? If so, how do I generate these certfiles ? By Cryptogen ?

Comment: Actually - you want to pass the flag to the `fabric-ca-client`  ... in your fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file, looks like tls is enabled and looks like the certs were autogenerated.  So you'll want to pass `--tls.certfiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/org1.tbp.com-cert.pem` as an option flag in your `fabric-ca-client` command line:  `fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://cn=admin,dc=example:admin@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/org1.tbp.com-cert.pem`

Comment: Thanks Gari ! The error evolved, now it is a "Post http://localhost:7054/enroll: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16"" following a Certificate Request.
The error is the same as before (unknown authority) when I use an HTTPS request.

Comment: @GariSingh I dropped using TLS for a start, maybe you can check up my following question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51825618/hyperledger-fabric-ca-connect-to-ldap-admin-does-not-exist