# Hyperledger Fabric-ca connect to LDAP : admin does not exist

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, openldap, ca, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to connect Hyperledger Fabric CA to an Openldap.
The Openldap is set up in local, with a single organisation

```
dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com
```

And a single user, cn=admin,dc=.../

I have set up a Fabric-CA with following server config :

```
ldap:
enabled: true
url: ldap://cn=admin,dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com:000000@☺localhost:389/dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com
userfilter: (dn:%s)
tls:
    enabled: false
attribute:
    names: ["dn"]
```

Converters and maps are irrelevant (so far). The admin exist in OpenLDAP, I checked.

When I start the following enroll command :

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://cn=admin,dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com@localhost:7054
```

I get the following error :

```
20 - Authorization failure
```

The CA debug log gave me these informations :

```
Received request for /enroll
ca.Config: "followed by the CA server config file"
Getting user 'cn=admin,dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com'
Searching for user 'cn=admin,dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com' using cached connection
127.0.0.1:45768 POST /enroll 401 23 "Failed to get user: User 'cn=admin,dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com' does not exist in LDAP directory"
```

Please, this issue is infuriating. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When we modify the fabric-ca-server-config.yaml, changing the url to :

      `ldap://cn=admin,dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com:000000@localhost:389/dc=com`

the error message change to :

      `Failed to get user: LDAP search failure; search request: &{BaseDN:dc=com Scope:2 DerefAliases:0 SizeLimit:0 TimeLimit:0 TypesOnly:false Filter:(dn:dc=admin,dc=fabric-ca,dc=example,dc=com) Attribute:[dn] Controls:[]}: LDAP Result Code 32 "No Such Object": "`

which is still an error.

Answer (score 0):

While performing enrollment process, you should pass user name only, but  you passed distinguished name instead of that. Except that password should be sent,  so your enrollment command should looks like:

```
fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:mypassword@localhost:7054
```

Except that, i think that userfilter should looks like that: `(cn=%s)` since you used `cn` as admin prefix

Comment: Hi @Aleksander,
Thanks for your comment. It doesn't work either.

Comment: @Pmuller i updated the answer, could you please change your userfilter to relate the admin prefix